# ng-click does not fire with a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am new with Angular and now I have encountered some problems...

So let's say I have a controller called ViewModelController and I use controlleras when I define the routes as following: [image].

And in my template I have just difened two div which seperate the container in two parts:

```
<div id='viewleft' class="divleft col-md-5"></div>
<div id='viewright' class="col-md-7 divright"></div>
```

And in ViewModelController, I have some code to render the template when the controller is loaded. **The question is that the ng-click I put in all the elements just don't fire and I don't really know where is the problem.**

I have tried thing like below but it just does not work.

```
  var content1 = '<ul><li><button id ="b1" ng-click="vmCtrl.cprint($event.target)">123</button></li><ul>';
  $("#viewleft").html(content1);
```

Can someone helps me on that? Thank you in advance, best wishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to compile this html so that angular code will work

```
$compile($("#viewleft").contents())(scope);
```

or better to use a directive that compile html when its value changes.

```
app.directive('compile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(
                function (scope) {
                    // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
                    return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
                },
                function (value) {
                    // when the 'compile' expression changes
                    // assign it into the current DOM
                    element.html(value);

                    // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
                    // scope.
                    // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
                    // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                }
            );
        };
    }]);
```

in controller you can asssign html to scope variable

```
$scope.template= '<ul><li><button id ="b1" ng-click="vmCtrl.cprint($event.target)">123</button></li><ul>';
```

and on view you can add that

```
<div id='viewleft' class="divleft col-md-5" compile="template"></div>
```

You can refer [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) docs for $compile.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering. Should I do any change in the codes of the compile directive if im using controller as syntax, i.e. vmCtrl instead of scope? Or it's just ok using it without change? Sorry be a bit annoying :p.

Comment: I don't think so but you have to test yourself :)